# Writing a 1D binary array of size N to a (N/2, N/2) size PPM image

Tags: c, ppm

I have the following code
'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int n = 32;
    int* img = malloc(sizeof(int)*n*n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) { 
        if(i%n < n/2) { 
            img[i] =   0;
        }
        else { 
            img[i] = 255;
        }
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen("img.ppm", "wb"); /* b - binary mode */
    fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", n, n);
    fwrite(img, sizeof(img), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    free(img);
}
```

But this is simply generating a blank image. I am not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Each pixel of a P6 PPM NetPBM image consists of 3 bytes. You're writing a bunch of `int`s, presumably 4 or 8 bytes each. This is probably not what you want. Moreover, I suspect you are misunderstanding what `sizeof(img)` does.

Comment: Also note, `32x32` byte block of memory has 4 times the number of bytes as a `16x16` 2D grid. Now that may be what you need if you are writing 4-bytes per-element in the `16x16` grid, but you have to ensure that is what you need. See the [PPM Format Specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) for the details of the image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. A type P6 NetPBM uses 3 bytes for each pixel (one byte for each of red, green, blue).  You are presumably writing a 32×32 image, so you would need 3 times more values than what you have (well, unless the use of `int`s was intentional, in which case you have *too many* values – we'll get back to that). I'll assume you actually want a grayscale image, so we'll switch to a *type P5* image. Furthermore, you are writing `int`s, and they are presumably 4 or 8 bytes long. Was this intentional? Lastly, `sizeof(img)` gives you the size of the type of `img`, which is pointer-to-`int`, i.e. 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system. It is *not* the size of your array.

Here's a suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> // I'll use uint8_t for the pixel bytes. That's personal preference, you can also stick with chars if you want.

int main() // Not relevant, but main should return int
{
    int n = 32;
    uint8_t * img = malloc(n*n); // Each pixel is a byte, an 8-bit unsigned integer.
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++) { 
        if(i%n < n/2) { 
            img[i] =   0;
        }
        else { 
            img[i] = 255;
        }
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen("img.ppm", "wb");
    fprintf(fp, "P5\n%d %d\n255\n", n, n); // P5 mode for grayscale, since you don't specify in your question what you want to do with colors.
    fwrite(img, 1, n*n, fp); // n*n pixel values, each 1 byte long.
    fclose(fp);
    free(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is to ask what hardware he is using. `void main()` may be perfectly correct if the OP is writing code on a microcontroller in a *freestanding environment* where program startup is implementation defined (there is no guarantee that the startup function will event be named `main()`)  Otherwise you are correct. See [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1) through [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. At any rate I shouldn't have confused the matter by bringing up the unrelated topic.

Comment: Well... It is always worth mentioning -- never know whether the OP is using 30 year old documentation that is now woefully incorrect `:)`

Comment: @David C. Rankin Interesting point. My background in physics (with a minor in CS) and this visualization is for a monte carlo simulation of a popular model to study phase change. So apologies if I am doing something stupid as I recently picked up C. My code runs on a supercomputer operated by my university (not sure if this info is enough). This problem is resolved now, however, I want to make sure I am not doing anything illegal in terms of modern C standards so thanks for sharing resources for it.

Comment: @thedeathstar1997 No no, you are not doing anything resulting in *Undefined Behavior*. I commend your choice of C. You could not have chosen a better language that provides complete low-level control of whatever hardware you happen to be using. More so than most languages, because of the control you are given as a programmer, C takes a bit longer become proficient in -- that time is well spent. Good luck with your coding!